# format/beautifier/reindent underscore code block

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am developing an application using **backbone** and **underscore**.

In my HTML page, I have some  blocks and they are mixed with some underscore code.

I used the template settings like:

print value: {{ value_name }}
excute code: {% code_to_execute %}

so, the source code contains heaps of {%    %} blocks and HTML tags.

I tired to use some online JS beautifier site, but they are not doing a good job to 
format codes into nice clean blocks. I also tried to use sublime's own Reindent, it doesn't help either.

I'm just wondering, if there are any tools exist to format underscore codes efficiently.

Comment: Try 'TidyUp' option in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Hi srvikram13, I tried that, but didn't get expected result

Comment: OK that was worth a try. You can also try installing **UniversalIndentGUI** plugin for Notepad++ & press `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+J` to format. Also, try setting the code formatting preferences within the editor you are using.

Comment: Even tho my comment is completely out of context, take it as a word of advice. Do NOT use code on your templates even if it is supported by the engine, it will become a massive problem down the road. I can even recommend you moving into Handlebars which enforces logic-less templates.

Comment: I'm used to sublime text2 menu select Edit → Line → Reindent

Comment: If Sublime Text is your cup of tee, maybe the package jsformat available at https://github.com/jdc0589/JsFormat would do the job. Install it through the Package Control.

Comment: Maybe this help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635460/formatting-code-within-notepad (similar to your case). If cant, I think you need to write custom formatter for underscore syntax (or change it to common syntax that used by JSP like <%%>).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Express is free and will format your code better than anything else I've seen. I might be a bit biased but Visual Studio IMHO is the best IDE Text Editor available. Web Storm is pretty decent as well.

Ctrl+K+D hotkey for quick formatting your text in VS.

[Visual Studio Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx)

[Web Storm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)

I would suggest if you are going to be doing a lot of coding do not rely on internet tools for developing and formatting just get yourself a nice Text Editor.