# notepad++ xml tag in one line

Tags: xml, notepad++

Whenever i open my XML in browser its tag are always open in one line like if there is an empty tag shown as example below.

[XML in Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S3hd.png)

but when i try to open same XML in notepad++ it shows me in this way mention below.

[XML in Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVHq3.png)

Is there any way can i get my reason and action tag in one line in notepad++.

Comment: Ensure Menu => **View** => **Show symbol** => **Show all characters** is ticked, then edit the file as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a auto-formatting in notepad++.

Try having a look at: [Formatting code in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635460/formatting-code-in-notepad)

Comment: This not the thing what i want. Please look into both images, How can i get tag in one line if it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the way that the web browser is interpreting the XML code, although you have a different format in Notepad++. This is totally normal, no need to worry - as long as there are no syntax errors.