# one button to change layout in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there a button or shortcut in notepad++ to change this:

```
<#if x?string=="true">${"first this"}${"then this"}${"last this"}<#if y?string=="true">${"plan B"}<#else><#if z?? && z?first??>${generic_number*100}${"%"}<#else>${sum_number*100}${"%"}</#if></#if></#if>
```

to this

```
<#if x?string=="true">
${"first this"}${"then this"}${"last this"}
<#if y?string=="true">
    ${"plan B"}
<#else>
    <#if z?? && z?first??>
        ${generic_number*100}${"%"}
    <#else>
        ${sum_number?first*100}${"%"}
    </#if>
</#if>
```

I need to see the hierarchy properly.
It takes me a long time to do this manually, especially for long code.

Thanks

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635460/formatting-code-in-notepad