# How to automatically add spaces between appropriate characters in Notepad++

Tags: formatting, notepad++

So I want to automatically turn this:

`x=10` into this `x = 10`

Or, for example

`for(i=0;i<10;i++)` into `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)`

Clicking some key or combination of keys in Notepad++.
And also I'd like to know what that procedure is called.
Forgive me for being dumb :) Thank you!

Comment: It's called Code Formatting and there is an answer for this already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635460/formatting-code-in-notepad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting code in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635460/formatting-code-in-notepad)