# How To Code A Macro For Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

So I'm wondering how to code a macro in notepad++ that applies for third party software, so like you set a macro to type '/fix all' in Minecraft for instance, but I have no idea how to go about it. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: That's not really what N++ is for.. You should look up AutoHotKey

Comment: possible duplication with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362444/how-to-write-macro-for-notepad