# How do I eliminate the auto-tabbing in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I checked the obvious space

`Setting->Preferences`

but could not find a way to do it.

Basically, whenever I hit enter, the cursor will return to the indent level, instead of the very left margin of the page.

I was able to set the tabs to use 4 spaces which is how I want it.

However, I only want to make tabs ( 4 spaces ) when I do it manually by hitting the tab button.

Currently programming in JavaScript.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118728/notepad-disable-auto-indent-after-empty-lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings->Preferences...->MISC.->Auto-indent (unchecked)